# Use a different shell by default in each terminal emulator

Tags: shell, terminal, terminal-emulator

I would like to change the default shell in each terminal emulator separately. To clarify, I want `xterm` to use `tcsh`, `pterm` to use `pysh`, `gnome-terminal` to use `bash`, etc. Is this possible? If so, how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each terminal emulator has its custom way to select which shell to run:

- gnome-terminal has the `run a custom command instead of my shell` field in the profile editor.
- xterm (and pterm) uses `xrdb database` to store its configuration but do not allow to configure the command to run. You could write a simple shell script that wraps the xterm executable to give him an *executable* parameter.
- konsole has the `command` field in the profile editor.

So you need to discover, by reading the manual, how (and if) each terminal emulator can be configured. There is no common way :-(

If you need only a simple way to choose which shell to run, I strongly suggest you to choose a terminal emulator that supports profiles (like gnome-terminal) and to create a different profile for each shell type. This way you'll can launch a new tab or window running the needed shell by the gnome-terminal internal menu (and, as bonus, choose a different text color for each shell).

Answer (score 1):

As a quick and contained solution, you could make a wrapper script.

```
case "$1" in
   xterm) shell=/bin/tcsh ;;
   pterm) shell=/bin/pysh ;;
   gnome-terminal) shell=/bin/bash ;;
   *)
       printf "Not supported: %s\n" "$1" >&2
       exit 1
esac

SHELL="$shell" "$1"
```

Just use it as such: `thescript <terminal_emulator>`.

It's generally preferable to configure each terminal emulator individually though.